# Full-screen Flash application test needs external pokes

Tags: java, flash, automated-tests

I'm testing a full-screen Flash application.  My preference is to drive the process with Java and I've had a lot of luck with the java.awt.Robot class.  I'm looking for ways of modifying the test's behavior while the app still occupies the full screen.

So far, I've found one "outside control", the caps lock key.  If I see the process go horribly wrong, I turn on caps lock.  Toolkit.getLockingKeyState notices that caps lock is on, and the test is terminated.

I need additional ways to change test operation, like "pause test" and "next test case."  It looks like I could use num lock and scroll lock, but my tests need to run on Mac OS X, Windows, and Linux, so I can't count on having those keys.  This is a small operation, so it's ok if the method isn't refined.  But not as kludgy as overloading the caps lock key with 5 different operations.

One last limitation: I have no internal control of the application; I'm supposed to "test" just like a user.

Comment: Is there any way to tell the full-screen Flash app to take up only 90% of the screen width?  Then my Java app window could have modification controls -- but it would still be hard, since the Robot has the mouse in constant motion in the Flash app.  That's why keyboard controls (caps lock) is so good here.

Comment: I just did a pseudo-test of the 90% idea using an external monitor instead.  As soon as I click on any app on the external monitor, the full-screen Flash app reverts to windowed mode.  So unless there's a way to prevent that, the 90% idea is junk.  I was hoping I didn't need to become a Flash expert for this project; maybe unrealistic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to control it from another machine over network, so you will be able to create control console or even gui and interact with your tester in any way you want. And if you run it on multiple machines, you can contol tests on all of them from one control panel.
It will be the most flexible way I think.

Comment: Interesting idea!  Creating a networked control would be a bit more work, but would allow infinite tweaking.